# a point of a subset in any topology either isolated or cluster point?

Tags: general-topology

for metric space, we can say a point must be isolated point or cluster point. In generally, why it is not true?
also, it is known that,
a set is closed iff it is contained all cluster point.
can we say, a set is closed iff it has no isolated point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, we can’t say that a set is closed iff it has no isolated: in a $T_1$ space every finite set is closed, and every point of a finite set is isolated in that set. On the other hand, the set $\Bbb Q$ of rationals has no isolated point, but it is not closed in $\Bbb R$.

It is true, however, that in any space every point of a set $A$ is either an isolated point of $A$ or a cluster point of $A$, simply because there is no third possibility.

Comment: Let the space is Hausdorff. Can we say if the space has no isolated points, then it must be closed Or which condition necessary for this?

Comment: @ege: Every space is a closed subset of itself, since $\varnothing$ is always an open set. Whether a set in a space is closed in a space is largely independent of whether it has any isolated points or not.

Comment: @ege: We can also say that a set is closed if it has no *cluster* points.

Comment: what is the importance of a space has no isolated points?

Comment: @ege: It depends on the context. In and of itself it has no particular significance; it’s just one extreme possibility. At the other extreme are so-called *scattered* spaces: $X$ is scattered if every subset of $X$ has an isolated point in its relative topology.